# Have an iAd be there in all scenes in the same state in the same position

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iad

I was wondering how can I have an ad be ON TOP OF THE SCREEN, for all my scenes, without it changing and just being there in the same state?
Anyone have the code for it? (swift)
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your app's `UIWindow` (you can find it in the app delegate) instead of a view controller/view.

Comment: How would I perform that in code? I'm in the app delegate and there is a variable called window, but what do I do with it?

Comment: `UIWindow` is a subclass of `UIView` so you can just do `[self.window addSubview:youriAd];`